# static WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr) vs non-static Impersonate()

Tags: c#, impersonation

I did some research on impersonation for a web application and I ended up using [this approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which basically uses `LogonUser`, `newId = new WindowsIdentity()` and `newId.Impersonate()`.

**Note**: *I preferred not to paste the whole code here so the post is not too long.*

This same code is used in several examples on the web, so it seems pretty reliable. But then I also found [this similar approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The first one uses this instance method:

```
public virtual WindowsImpersonationContext Impersonate()
```

And the second one, this static method:

```
public static WindowsImpersonationContext Impersonate(IntPtr userToken)
```

The only difference in the example code is this:

```
using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
{
    using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
    {
        // Check the identity.
        Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
    }
}
```

vs

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
{
    // Check the identity.
    Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
}
```

Is there any advantage of one against the other? Just for the sake of simplicity, I think the second one is preferable if the `WindowsIdentity` object is not used in any other way.

**Sub question 1**: is this code at the beginning of the class needed? It is never called and commenting it doesn't seem to affect the functionality at all. Only the one in `SafeTokenHandle` is called.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
```

**Sub question 2**: is calling to `Undo()` necessary if I will dispose the `WindowsImpersonationContext` object anyway? For example:

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
{
    // Whatever
    impersonatedUser.Undo(); // Is this useful?
}
```

The documentation recommends calling it but fails to specify if `Dispose()` already does that. From what I've tested, disposing the object is enough.

**Sub question 3**: what's the advantage of calling `DuplicateToken()` or `RevertToSelf()`? I've seen them in some examples like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4051/Windows-Impersonation-using-C) and [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=10090&zep=ImpersonatorDemo%2FImpersonator.cs&rzp=%2FKB%2Fcs%2Fzetaimpersonator%2F%2Fzetaimpersonator_demo.zip), but I couldn't find any reason to use them.

Thanks a lot for reading my whole post,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

The static method internally calls the same code, so it's more of a shortcut.

No, you do not need to call Undo if you're using it in a using block, as Dispose will call Undo.  You should use it in the using block to properly handle exceptions being thrown and what not, unless you know what you're doing.

I'm not sure why the CloseHandle is there in the first class.